# A much tidier solution is required

Tags: excel, vba

'This is an extract from an Excel VBA programme to extract a "day number" and "-1,0,+1" flag from a table called Calender of Events. Column 1 - Event "x", Column 2 day of the month number, Column 3 -1,0 or +1.
'The Events are NOT described as Event 1, Event 2 etc. but have various (fixed) descriptions.
'The "Active Cell" is the date (1st) column in my workbook Page 1, the "Event x" is the description (3rd) column on the same page.
'The Calender of Events is a 3 column table in my workbook Page 2
'Line 580 checks to see if the "new" date is a weekend or Bank Holiday and adjusts appropriately, some by adding days, others by deducting days
'Determined by a "Flag" set to one of a selection of numbers (-1,0 or +1). The "Flag" is set by "Flag = ", also determined by the Table Calender of Events.Column 3.'
'This is very "unwieldy", there must be a tidier way.'

```
    Dim Calender_of_Events(1 To 100, 1 To 2) As Variant   'Array to hold the Dates of the Calender of Events.
    'Dim x, Dim u etc

Windows("Calender of Events.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Page 2").Select

    'Populate Calender_of_Events

x = Range("W2").Value                                                   'No. of Lines in the Table (Page 2 - Column W (Col 23))
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 23).Select

    For u = 1 To (x + 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        Calender_of_Events(u, 1) = ActiveCell()
        Calender_of_Events(u, 2) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
    Next u


Windows("Calender of Events.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Page 1").Select


Line260:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = "Event 1") Then Else GoTo Line270                                            'Not "Event 1" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 1", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990
            A234 = Application.VLookup("Event 1", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)                                                           '"No Match" Else "Match"
            C210 = CDate((A234) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line270:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = "Event 2") Then Else GoTo Line280                           'Not "Event 2" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 2", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990                           '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A244 = Application.VLookup("Event 2", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A244) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line280:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) = "Event 3" Then Else GoTo Line290       'Not "Event 3" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 3", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990       '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A253 = Application.VLookup("Event 3", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A253) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line290:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) = "Event 4" Then Else GoTo Line300             'Not "Event 4" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 4", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990   '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A259 = Application.VLookup("Event 4", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A259) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line300:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) = "Event 5" Then Else GoTo Line310        'Not "Event 5" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 5", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990   '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A265 = Application.VLookup("Event 5", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A265) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line310:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) = "Event 6" Then Else GoTo Line320                                   'Not "Event 6" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 6", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990                         '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A270 = Application.VLookup("Event 6", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A270) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line320:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) = "Event 7" Then Else GoTo Line330                               'Not "Event 7" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 7", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990                     '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A275 = Application.VLookup("Event 7", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A275) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line330:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) = "Event 8" Then Else GoTo Line340                                 'Not "Event 8" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 8", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990  '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A280 = Application.VLookup("Event 8", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A280) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line340:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) = "Event 9" Then Else GoTo Line350                                  'Not "Event 9" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 9", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990                        '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A285 = Application.VLookup("Event 9", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A285) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580

Line350:
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)) = "Event 10" Then Else GoTo Line360                          'Not "Event 10" then go to the next detail
        If (IsError(Application.VLookup("Event 10", Calender_of_Events, 2, False))) Then GoTo Line990     '"No Match" Else "Match"
            A294 = Application.VLookup("Event 10", Calender_of_Events, 2, False)
            C210 = CDate((A294) & "/" & (A174) & "/" & (Input_Year))
            ActiveCell.Value = C210
            C202 = ActiveCell()
            z = 0: GoTo Line580
```

Comment: Start by using different logic instead of relying on `GoTo` statements. That is not a good way to write code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry for posting this. The answer is fundamentally so simple, I can't quite understand why I couldn't see it in the first place.
Maybe it's because I've come froman age where I used Macro's a lot. VBA is far more flexible and powerful, and I'm still struggling with some of the available functions (much more than with Macro's).
If the moderators have no objection I would like to delete this "question" from the forum - or thay can do it for me.
Thanks

Comment: Could you post the answer?

Comment: @donPablo, Please just bear with me for a couple of days. I'm very busy at the moment, but I will give you my answer. I'm not certain it's the best solution, but it's certainly tidier than my original code.